# How to treat Regular Expression as plain text while using .Net Regex Class?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

How to escape all regex characters automatically using built-in .NET mechanism or something like that?

I am using Regex class to find match for a regular expression. See example below.

```
string pattern = "abc";
Regex regexp = new Regex(@"a\w", RegexOptions.None);
if (regexp.IsMatch(pattern))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found");
}
```

So, here Found will hit.

Now, in some cases, I still want to use Regex class but treat Regular Expression as plain string. So, for example, I will change pattern string to @"a\w" and need Regex class should find the match.

```
string pattern = @"a\w";
Regex regexp = new Regex(@"a\w", RegexOptions.None);
if (regexp.IsMatch(pattern))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found");
}
```

In the above case also, "Found" should hit.
So, the question is how to convert or treat Regular Expression into/as a plain string or something like that which can be used in a Regex Class? How to achieve the above code snippet scenario?

Note: - I do not want to use string.Contains, string.IndexOf, etc for plain text string matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "de-regex" your string through [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx). This will transform your pattern-to-search-for into the correctly escaped regex version.

```
string pattern = @"a\w";
Regex regexp = new Regex(Regex.Escape(@"a\w"), RegexOptions.None);
if (regexp.IsMatch(pattern))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found");
}
```

Comment: How to escape all regex characters automatically using built-in .NET mechanism or something like that?

Comment: That's what that method is for. It transforms the input string into a regex-string that matches the literal input.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case you don't want to search for what `\w` means in regex, you want to search for the literal `\w`, so you'd want:

```
string pattern = @"a\w";
Regex regexp = new Regex(@"a\\w", RegexOptions.None);
if (regexp.IsMatch(pattern))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found");
}
```

(Note the escaping).

Comment: Actually, @"a\w" or @"a\\w" will be a user input from a UI's Text Box. So, it's the internal code implementation's responsibilty to modify the input pattern. User may have the option that she chooses the Matching as Regular Expression or Literal (plain). In that case pattern string has to be modified in non-regular expression text. Is there any way to that programmatically.

Comment: im not aware of any built in mechanism, although id be interested if anyone else knows of one. Manually you will have to escape all regex characters, i.e. replace `[` with `\[`, `(` with `\(`, `.` with `\.` etc.

Comment: Please see Hans's answer below. You can "de-regex" your string through Regex.Escape. This will transform your pattern-to-search-for into the correctly escaped regex version

Comment: woo, didnt know about that! awesome :D

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape your special characters like: `@"a\\w"`

Comment: three slashes? think you mean two